# Adding file pattern to sitemesh decorator

Tags: jsp, sitemesh

I have the following sitemesh decorator definition:

```
<decorator name="bootstrap-decorator" page="bootstrap-decorator.jsp">
    <pattern>/users</pattern>
    <pattern>/customers</pattern>
    <pattern>/shoppers</pattern>
</decorator>
```

The above 3 patterns all go to a single JSP page "home.jsp".

What I want to do:

Remove all the pattern definitions and include only one generic pattern "/*" and some how declare the output page pattern "home.jsp". Basically, I want sitemesh to apply the decorator based on the output page pattern.

How can I achieve this? or can this be at all achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

We can achieve this by adding a meta tag in the jsp page specifying the decorators name

```
<meta name="decorator" content="bootstrap-decorator"/>
```

It uses the PageDecoratorMapper declared in sitemesh.xml.

Reference:
[Decorating Beyond URL Patterns](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/wiki/display/sitemesh/Decorating+Beyond+URL+Patterns)